# How to commit individual transaction in Oracle PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, transactions

I need to write a PL/SQL procedure, within this procedure I need to call another procedure within its own transaction bounds, and commit it regardless of failure or commit of main transaction. In other words I need something like `REQUIRES NEW` transaction propagation.

Something like:

```
procedure mainProcedure(arugements) is 
begin
    // some statements
    nestedProcedure(someArguments);
    // some other statements
end;

procedure nestedProcedure(arguments) is
begin
  // start a new transaction
  // some statements, lock some objects!
  // commit the new transaction and release locked objects
end;
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use `pragma autonomous_transaction`. It does the same what you need. But don't forget that in the sub transaction you will not see any updates from above transactions.

```
procedure mainProcedure(arugements) is 
begin
    // some statements
    nestedProcedure(someArguments);
    // some other statements
end;

procedure nestedProcedure(arguments) is
pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
  // start a new transaction
  // some statements, lock some objects!
  // commit the new transaction and release locked objects
  commit; 
end;
```

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at [Autonomous transation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/autotransaction_pragma.htm#LNPLS01302). Also see demo

```
CREATE TABLE t (
 test_value VARCHAR2(25));

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE child_block IS
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO t
   (test_value)
   VALUES
   ('Child block insert');
  COMMIT; 
END child_block;
 /

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE parent_block IS

BEGIN
   INSERT INTO t
   (test_value)
   VALUES
   ('Parent block insert');

    child_block;

    ROLLBACK; 
END parent_block;
 /
```

Execution:

```
 -- empty the test table
    TRUNCATE TABLE t;

   -- run the parent procedure
     exec parent_block;

   -- check the results
    SELECT * FROM t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a (Commit single transaction Procedure), you can create the procedure and use it as illustrated in the comments.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SWD_AUTON_DML (p_dmlstat VARCHAR2)
AS
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN                                       -- Main transaction suspends here.
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE p_dmlstat;         -- Autonomous transaction begins here.

   COMMIT;                                -- Autonomous transaction ends here.
END;                                         -- Main transaction resumes here.


--------------------- How to USE -------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------
---EXECUTE AUTON_DML(q'[UPDATE staging_pm_schedule_table SET NOTE = 'TEST_Variable']');
--OR
---EXECUTE AUTON_DML('UPDATE staging_pm_schedule_table SET NOTE = '''TEST_Variable'''');
```

for more information:
https://brainsdazed.blogspot.com/2018/09/oracle-procedure-to-commit-per-dml.html

Comment: Links should be references, the relevant parts for the question should be written in your answer not in an external resource.

Comment: @KamiKaze Sorry my bad, what about now?

Comment: looks good but I can not say anything whether it is correct.(Not my field of work)