# How to Commit only one query during Oracle stored procedure runtime

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using SQL developer. I have a stored procedure that is running a long time. I need to trace what happens during that run time.

I tried with `DBMS_output.put_line('trace');`. But it print after the stored procedure has completed. Also I can't use `DBMS_trace` (might be older version I am using).

So I came up with idea. I would like to insert into table during stored procedure run time. How can I Commit only that insert query in stored procedure?

Comment: You might want to have a look at ["How to commit individual transaction in Oracle PLSQL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107629).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two possibilities.

Either you write a procedure which inserts log messages into a table. Declare this procedure with `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WriteLogMsg(LogMessage IN VARCHAR2) IS
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;      
BEGIN

   INSERT INTO T_LOG_ENTRIES (LOG_DATE, LOG_MESSAGE) 
   VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, LogMessage);
   COMMIT;

END WriteLogMsg;
```

Or use the `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO` package:

```
PROCEDURE LONG_RUNNING_PROCEDURE IS
BEGIN

DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE('LONG_RUNNING_PROCEDURE', 'Starting');
...

DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_ACTION('Still working, please be patient'); 
...

DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_ACTION('Finished');

-- DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE(NULL, NULL); -> removes entries for MODULE and ACTION

END;
```

While the procedure is running you can query information with

```
SELECT USERNAME, MODULE, ACTION
from V$SESSION
where USERNAME = ...;
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you have to use the Pragma Autonomous transactions.

Create a new procedure with Pragma Autonomous.

```
PROCEDURE test_autonomous 
IS
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
   insert ....
   commit;
END test_autonomous;
```

now call this procedure in your code. this will do your trick. You can all use the parameters to pas some data you want to insert.